# Show that any representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ is a subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes m} \oplus V^{\otimes {(m+1)}}$ for some $m$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Suppose $M$ be a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, then there is a positive integer $m$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes m} \oplus V^{\otimes {(m+1)}}$,where $V$ is the standard $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$.

Since $M$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, by the complete reducibility theorem $ M=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n V(n_i)^{\oplus a_i} \oplus\bigoplus\limits_{j=1}^m V(m_j)^{\oplus b_j}$ where all $a_i$ and $b_j$ are distinct and $a_i$ and $b_j$ are multiplicities of $V(n_i)$ and $V(m_j)$, respectively, and $n_i$'s are odd and $m_j$'s are even.  Any ideas to proceed further?

Comment: "Where V is the standard 2 dimensional representation of SL(2,C)" are you sure about these 2s?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yeah $V$ is standard $2$ dimensional rep of $sl(2,\bf C)$[traceless matrices].

Comment: Well, you kept the 2s but changed the cs...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez   I think $V$ is $\bf C^2$ and the action is by ,matrix multiplication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(w)$ denote the simple $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-module with $\mathfrak{h}$-highest weight $w\in\mathbb{C}$ with respect to the Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ consisting of upper-triangular matrices, where the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is the subalgebra composed by diagonal matrices.  Then, $V=L(1)$.  Observe that $$V^{\otimes n}=\bigoplus_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\,\big(L(n-2j)\big)^{\oplus \left(\binom{n}{j}-\binom{n}{j-1}\right)}$$
for all positive integers $n$.  As you have stated, $M$ can be decomposed as $$M=\left(\bigoplus_{\mu=0}^r\,\big(L\left(a_\mu\right)\big)^{\oplus k_\mu}\right)\oplus\left(\bigoplus_{\nu=0}^s\,\big(L\left(b_\nu\right)\big)^{\oplus l_\nu}\right)$$
where $r,s\in\mathbb{N}_0$, $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_r\in\mathbb{N}$, $l_1,l_2\ldots,l_s\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_r$ are nonnegative even integers, and $b_1<b_2<\ldots<b_s$ are nonnegative odd integers.  Now, we can pick $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$m\geq 2+ \max\left\{a_r,b_s,k_1-1,k_2-1,\ldots,k_r-1,l_1-1,l_2-1,\ldots,l_s-1
\right\}\,.$$  Ergo, it follows that $M$ is a direct summand of $V^{\otimes m}\oplus V^{\otimes (m+1)}$.

Comment: Sorry..is it obvious that $V^{\otimes n}=\bigoplus_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\,\big(L(n-2j)\big)^{\oplus\binom{n-1}{j}}$ ?

Comment: You can first show that the weight space of $V^{\otimes n}$ with weight $n-2j$ is of dimension $\binom{n}{j}$ for every $j=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: I also made a counting error (as $\binom{n-1}{j}\neq \binom{n}{j}-\binom{n}{j-1}$).  Please see the edit.